# terraform gives me error in function call when using element

Tags: routes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, vpc

Hi i keep getting an error.

the error I get:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on vpc.tf line 57, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_subnet":
  57:   subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)
    |----------------
    | aws_subnet.private is empty tuple
    | count.index is 1

Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
list.

variable "private_subnets_cidrs" {
  description = "The CIDR range for the private subnets"
  type        = list(string)
}
```

I have added my subnet  and route table association resource for you to examine.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count                           = local.max_subnet_length
  vpc_id                          = aws_vpc.proxy_vpc.id
  cidr_block                      = var.private_subnets_cidrs[count.index]
  availability_zone               = element(var.azs, count.index)
}
```

`private_subnets_cidrs = ["10.9.*.*/2*", "10.9.*.*/2*"]`

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_subnet" {
  count          = length(var.private_subnets_cidrs) > 0 ? length(var.private_subnets_cidrs) : 0
  subnet_id      = element(concat(aws_subnet.private.*.id), count.index)
  route_table_id = element(aws_route_table.private.*.id, count.index)
}
```

Please can someone please help me,.
How do I fix this? I want to be able to associate each subnet to each route table

Comment: Your error doesn't match your Terraform code. Can you check that the code in your question properly produces the error you have please? Your question should also include a [mcve] where possible. This would mean including the `aws_subnet.private` resource that is being looped over as well.

Comment: ... error looks clear `aws_subnet.private is empty tuple`

Comment: thank you. I have added the subnet and I believe that I have abided by the minimal reproducible example

Comment: `local.max_subnet_length` seems to be `0`. how is this calculated?

Comment: local.max_subnet_length. = length(var.private_subnets_cidrs)